# Google Chrome Extension removed results in failure

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am using Google Chrome, on Windows 7.

I ended up with am extra toolbar - I believe it was after I updated java, while I was doing some work and I may not have paid attention to a checkbox - there is no other way this could have happened.

Still, I ended up with this extra toolbar (Ask toolbar).

Very colorful, pretty and all. I didn't want it. I didn't want the button that came with it. I don't want bells and whistles.

So I went to the Extensions page, to remove it.

It said (and still says):

```
(This extension is managed and cannot be removed or disabled.)
```

I am usually not satisfied with a simple NO, so I searched the web for the particular extension, and this message, and found that I could just delete the folder from the Extensions folder of Chrome.

Ok, done. Deleted the folder.

Since then, new tabs will always load the following error:

```
    No webpage was found for the web address: chrome-
extension://aaaaojmikegpiepcfdkkjaplodkpfmlo/config/skin/new-tab.html
```

Gmail page loads in a lower corner, with the top corner reserved for a frame that says the same thing.

Search engines - same... though it takes a bit and then they usually refresh and show on the whole page.

Most pages manage to render correctly after showing the error frame section.

I have tried to use the restore from Windows but it could not restore the removed folder. (not that I wanted the evil extension back, but this is worse).

I will probably have to uninstall Chrome...

After I save some of my history.

Still, this is annoying - and I bet it will happen again.

Any ideas ?

How can I fix this extension mess ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did -

Add and remove programs - uninstalled the extension.

I was not aware that it was a separate program... Good to know for the future (I feel so silly - such a simple solution).